# Evaluation of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(x^{k}+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Can anyone find a simplified expression for the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\left(x^{k}+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)^k$? I have tried expanding the first few terms but it gets a little messy with no clear leads. I suspect formulae for geometric series may come into it somehow, but at the moment it isn't clear how to start.

Comment: It's from an Olympiad paper I believe, so I assumed there would be a neat solution, with no need for double sums etc.

Comment: I honestly have no clue.  After binomial expansion, you end up with things like $x^{k^2}$, which have no closed form sum.

Comment: Exactly. I tried to see if expanding the first brackets could lead to some pattern and then proceed by induction, but it's a dead end.

Comment: Is this part of a bigger problem?Also from what Olympiad is this?

Comment: Interesting, even [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En+(x%5Ek%2B1%2F(x%5Ek))%5Ek) can't figure it out.

Comment: I found this on a website a while ago and it was listed under olympiad questions, but I don't know specifically where it came from. It's a standalone problem.

Comment: @Will: is the original problem really about simplifying such sum, or just about evaluating the coefficient of $x^0$ in the Laurent series?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S(n)$ be your sum.
For $1 \le m \le n^2$, the coefficient of $x^m$ (and of $x^{-m}$, by symmetry) in $S(n)$ is 
$$ [x^m]\; S(n) = \sum_k {k \choose \frac{m}{2k}+\frac{k}{2}}$$
where the sum is over all divisors $k$ of $m$ such that $m \le k^2 \le n^2$
and $\frac{m}{k} \equiv k \mod 2$.  In particular this is $0$ if $m \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

The coefficient of $x^0$ in $S(n)$ is $$ [x^0] \; S(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {2j \choose j}$$

Comment: My guess, based on the usual approximation to $\binom{2j}{j}$, is that $\sum_{j=1}^m \binom{2j}{j}
\approx \dfrac{4^m}{\sqrt{\pi }}\dfrac{4}{3\sqrt{m}}$.

Comment: @martycohen See [OEIS sequence A066796](https://oeis.org/A066796), in particular the formula by Vaclav Kotesovec, which agrees with your guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a long comment;

Not sure how to proceed, but one way to rewrite it is $x=e^{i\phi}$, getting

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2\cos k\phi)^k=\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k T_k^k(\cos(\phi))$$
where $T$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.

It seems to me that the expression is too convoluted to expect a nice solution. Another similar approach that might be considered is to express everything with $x+x^{-1}$. We have expressions of the type

$$(x+x^{-1})^2=2+(x^2+x^{-2})$$
$$(x+x^{-1})^3=3(x+x^{-1})+(x^3+x^{-3})$$
which could be solved for $x^k+x^{-k}$ but I can't see how to get a closed form for a general term. This solution does give you the constant term (reproduces result by @RobertIsrael) but the rest gets complicated due to $()^k$ - we get summations over very strange sets.

A [reference](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2015/950695/) that might be useful - it includes some very similar expressions.